# How to return nested objects of many-to-many relationship with autoquery

Tags: servicestack

Lets say I have 3 classes:

```
public class Book
{
    [Autoincrement]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
    [Reference]
    public list<BookAuthor> BookAuthors {get; set;}
}

public class BookAuthor
{
    [ForeignKey(typeof(Book))]
    public int BookId {get; set;}
    [Reference]
    public Book Book {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Author))]
    public int AuthorId {get; set;}
    [Reference]
    public Author Author {get; set;}
}

public class Author
{
    [Autoincrement]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

There is a many-to-many relationship between books and authors.

This is common issue for app I am currently building and I need to give a DTO like this to front end:

```
public class BookDto
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public list<Author> Authors {get; set;}
}
```

The front end needs the Author embedded. I need a way of getting the Authors nested inside the DTO in a single query.

Is this possible?

Comment: I have no idea how your language in question works, but it seems redundant to define a relationship on the Book object via an array of link objects. Why wouldn't Book just have an array (list) of Authors and Author have an array of Books? If there's additional heavy lifting on a deeper level, like a relational database, it should be able to do the lookup based on the variable name itself as the relationship name and the Book I'd as the left side join key.

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure I am getting you.  Let's say I want to get all the books an author has wrote.  How would I do that if authors is an array on book?

Comment: Author objects wouldn't exists inside the Books>Authors array, that would just be the pointer to Authors related to the book. Conversely, Authors would have a Books array to get all the related direction in that direction. But I suspect I'm just misunderstanding how the language works.

Comment: Or maybe it's just me hung up on naming conventions. Like maybe it would make more sense to me if it was `list<BookAuthor> Authors` so that it was clear that you are retrieving a list of authors, not retrieving the relationship itself. But even then, it seems like the type should reflect what will be inside the list itself. Again, probably overthinking it as well as imposing my general view of something onto a language pattern I don't actually know.

Comment: Or some more overthinking: the list type should be BookAuthors, but it should be defined as being a BookAuthors list of Author objects, informing the Book object both of how to fetch the objects (via the BookAuthors getter method) and how to interact with the results (as a list of Authors). Then Authors would use the same BookAuthors list type, but it would be defined as a list of that type containing Book objects.

Comment: You can't define a many-to-many relationship like that.  You need a junction table.  Some ORM hide the junction table with an abstraction but it has to exist.

Comment: I know it has to exist at the database level (in a rdbms model), I am more reflecting on how it should exist in an object oriented context. The BookAuthors variable isn't a list of BookAuthor objects, it's a list of Author objects. In a hypermedia context, BookAuthors would be the link while Authors would be the resource. My interface should know that it is getting a list of authors that follow a certain scheme. The only reason BookAuthors is interesting to my client would be if Books and Authors are related in different ways and I need to specify which relationship I'm wanting.

Comment: If you look at answer it might make more sense.  The ORM has to map a class to table but the related item is nested in the DTO.  This was the essence of my question and was answered by mythz with very detailed breakdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a live example to do what you want [you can play with on Gistlyn](https://gistlyn.com/?gist=9c2565c4d8a788306e93b139426a7aef&collection=2cc6b5db6afd3ccb0d0149e55fdb3a6a).

In OrmLite every Data Model class maps 1:1 with the underlying table and there's no magic support for M:M queries, you have to use them as the different tables as their stored in the RDBMS.

Also every table needs a unique Primary Id in OrmLite which is missing in `BookAuthor` which I've added, I've also added a `[UniqueConstraint]` to enforce no duplicate relationships, with these changes the resulting classes looks like:

```
public class Book
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
    [Reference] 
    public List<BookAuthor> BookAuthors {get; set;}
}

[UniqueConstraint(nameof(BookId), nameof(AuthorId))]
public class BookAuthor
{
    [AutoIncrement] public int Id {get; set;} 

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Book))]
    public int BookId {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Author))]
    public int AuthorId {get; set;}
}

public class Author
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class BookDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Author> Authors { get; set; }
}
```

Then create tables and add some sample data:

```
db.CreateTable<Book>();
db.CreateTable<Author>();
db.CreateTable<BookAuthor>();

var book1Id = db.Insert(new Book { Title = "Book 1" }, selectIdentity:true);
var book2Id = db.Insert(new Book { Title = "Book 2" }, selectIdentity:true);
var book3Id = db.Insert(new Book { Title = "Book 3" }, selectIdentity:true);

var authorAId = db.Insert(new Author { Name = "Author A" }, selectIdentity:true);
var authorBId = db.Insert(new Author { Name = "Author B" }, selectIdentity:true);

db.Insert(new BookAuthor { BookId = 1, AuthorId = 1 });
db.Insert(new BookAuthor { BookId = 1, AuthorId = 2 });
db.Insert(new BookAuthor { BookId = 2, AuthorId = 2 });
db.Insert(new BookAuthor { BookId = 3, AuthorId = 2 });
```

Then to select multiple tables in a single query in OrmLite you can use [SelectMulti](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#selecting-multiple-columns-across-joined-tables), e.g:

```
var q = db.From<Book>()
    .Join<BookAuthor>()
    .Join<BookAuthor,Author>()
    .Select<Book,Author>((b,a) => new { b, a });
var results = db.SelectMulti<Book,Author>(q);
```

As the property names [follows the reference conventions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#typed-sqlexpression-support-for-joins) their joins don't need to be explicitly specified as they can be implicitly inferred.

This will return a `List<Tuple<Book,Author>>` which you can then use a dictionary to stitch all the authors with their books:

```
var booksMap = new Dictionary<int,BookDto>();
results.Each(t => {
    if (!booksMap.TryGetValue(t.Item1.Id, out var dto))
        booksMap[t.Item1.Id] = dto = t.Item1.ConvertTo<BookDto>();        
    if (dto.Authors == null) 
        dto.Authors = new List<Author>();
    dto.Authors.Add(t.Item2);
});
```

We can get the list of books from the Dictionary Values:

```
var dtos = booksMap.Values;
dtos.PrintDump();
```

Where the books are populated with its Authors and prints out:

```
[
    {
        Id: 1,
        Title: Book 1,
        Authors: 
        [
            {
                Id: 1,
                Name: Author A
            },
            {
                Id: 2,
                Name: Author B
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        Id: 2,
        Title: Book 2,
        Authors: 
        [
            {
                Id: 2,
                Name: Author B
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        Id: 3,
        Title: Book 3,
        Authors: 
        [
            {
                Id: 2,
                Name: Author B
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

#### AutoQuery

[AutoQuery](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery) can only implement implicit queries that it can automate, if you need to do any custom queries or projections you would need to provide a [custom AutoQuery implementation](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#custom-autoquery-implementations), since the joins can be implicitly inferred it's possible you could let AutoQuery construct the joined query so you only have to provide the custom `Select()` projection and mapping yourself, e.g:

```
[Route("/books/query")]
public class QueryBooks : QueryDb<Book,BookDto>, 
    IJoin<Book,BookAuthor>,
    IJoin<BookAuthor,Author> {}

public class MyQueryServices : Service
{
    public IAutoQueryDb AutoQuery { get; set; }

    //Override with custom implementation
    public object Any(QueryBooks query)
    {
        var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(query, base.Request)
            .Select<Book,Author>((b,a) => new { b, a });
        var results = db.SelectMulti<Book,Author>(q);

        var booksMap = new Dictionary<int,BookDto>();
        results.Each(t => {
            if (!booksMap.TryGetValue(t.Item1.Id, out var dto))
                booksMap[t.Item1.Id] = dto = t.Item1.ConvertTo<BookDto>();        
            if (dto.Authors == null) 
                dto.Authors = new List<Author>();
            dto.Authors.Add(t.Item2);
        });
        return new QueryResponse<BookDto> { Results = booksMap.Values.ToList() };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mythz.  Is it possible to do this with AutoQuery?  The front end wants to use the implicit queries.  Can select multi be combined with autoquery?  I want to be able to have all of the filters stay working but nest authors in the QueryResponse<BookDto>

Comment: @Guerrilla No AutoQuery can only create queries that can be implicitly automated, you can try adding a custom implementation, I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks Mythz, I really appreciate the update for AutoQuery

Comment: Hi Mythz, this doesn't work if `Book` doesnt't have an `Author`.  When using SelectMulti in this way it does't return every `Book`.  It only returns the `Book` that have a `Author`.  I need to return every book with the author optionally null.  Is that possible?  I need to return collection of Books and if they have an author nest it, if not then nothing is nested.

Comment: @Guerrilla That's the behavior of inner joins otherwise you'd need to use `ILeftJoin`

Comment: I will make another question to show you the difficulty im having