# Getting pagination to work with one to many join

Tags: servicestack

I'm currently working on a database with several one-to-many and many-to-many relationships and I am struggling getting ormlite to work nicely.

I have a one-to-many relationship like so:

```
var q2 = Db.From<GardnerRecord>()
    .LeftJoin<GardnerRecord, GardnerEBookRecord>((x, y) => x.EanNumber == y.PhysicalEditionEan)
```

I need to return a collection of `ProductDto` that has a nested list of `GardnerEBookRecord`.

Using the `SelectMult()` technique it doesn't work because the pagination breaks as I am condensing the left joined results to a smaller collection so the page size and offsets are all wrong (This method: [How to return nested objects of many-to-many relationship with autoquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56674452/how-to-return-nested-objects-of-many-to-many-relationship-with-autoquery))

To get the paging right I need to be able to do something like:

```
select r.*, count(e) as ebook_count, array_agg(e.*)
from gardner_record r
       left join gardner_e_book_record e
                 on r.ean_number = e.physical_edition_ean
group by r.id
```

There are no examples of this in the docs and I have been struggling to figure it out.  I can't see anything  that would function like `array_agg` in the `Sql` object of OrmLite.

I have tried variations of:

```
var q2 = Db.From<GardnerRecord>()
    .LeftJoin<GardnerRecord, GardnerEBookRecord>((x, y) => x.EanNumber == y.PhysicalEditionEan)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Id).Limit(100)
    .Select<GardnerRecord, GardnerEBookRecord>((x, y) => new { x, EbookCount = Sql.Count(y), y }) //how to aggregate y?

var res2 = Db.SelectMulti<GardnerRecord, GardnerEBookRecord>(q2);
```

and

```
var q2 = Db.From<GardnerRecord>()
    .LeftJoin<GardnerRecord, GardnerEBookRecord>((x, y) => x.EanNumber == y.PhysicalEditionEan)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Id).Limit(100)
    .Select<GardnerRecord, List<GardnerEBookRecord>>((x, y) => new { x, y });

var res = Db.SqlList<object>(q2);
```

But I can't work out how to aggregate the GardnerEBookRecord to a list and keep the paging and offset correct.

Is this possible?  Any workaround?

edit:

I made project you can run to see issue:

https://github.com/GuerrillaCoder/OneToManyIssue

Database added as a docker you can run `docker-compose up`.  Hopefully this shows what I am trying to do

Comment: You're not going to be able to use a Typed query in OrmLite to construct postgres-specific queries, here's [some examples of selecting Custom SQL APIs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#typed-sqlexpressions-with-custom-sql-apis) and [Custom Select SQL](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#custom-sql-fragments). I wont be able to workout if the result set of your query is supported without being able to run it, if you can put together a stand-alone example I can run to create the tables + rows to run the query I can run it on my side to see if its supported.

Comment: I have added a github repo with code and data seed to run.  I gave commentary in coments of what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Npgsql doesn't support reading an unknown array or records column type, e.g `array_agg(e.*)` which fails with:

> Unhandled Exception: System.NotSupportedException: The field 'ebooks' has a type currently unknown to Npgsql (OID 347129).

But it does support reading an array of integers with `array_agg(e.id)` which you can query instead:

```
var q = @"select b.*, array_agg(e.id) ids from book b
         left join e_book e on e.physical_book_ean = b.ean_number
         group by b.id";

var results = db.SqlList<Dictionary<string,object>>(q);
```

This will return a [Dictionary Dynamic Result Set](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#select-data-from-multiple-tables-into-dynamic-resultsets) which you'll need to combine into a distinct id collection to query all ebooks referenced, e.g:

```
//Select All referenced EBooks in a single query  
var allIds = new HashSet<int>();
results.Each(x => (x["ids"] as int[])?.Each(id => allIds.Add(id)));
var ebooks = db.SelectByIds<EBook>(allIds);
```

Then you can create a dictionary mapping of `id => Ebook` and use it to populate a collection of ebooks entities using the ids for each row:

```
var ebooksMap = ebooks.ToDictionary(x => x.Id);
results.Each(x => x[nameof(ProductDto.Ebooks)] = (x["ids"] as int[])?
    .Where(id => id != 0).Map(id => ebooksMap[id]) );
```

You can then use [ServiceStack AutoMapping Utils](https://docs.servicestack.net/auto-mapping) to convert each Object Dictionary into your Product DTO:

```
var dtos = results.Map(x => x.ConvertTo<ProductDto>());
```

Comment: Thank you, that is much nicer way of doing it than one by one!